# iOS Swift App crash : while sorting an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, sorting

App Crash at the last line only on iOS16.0.1 not the older one. below is the code

```
let unique = self.messagesList.meesageList.unique{$0.id}

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"

messagesSortedList = unique.sorted { dateFormatter.date(from: $0.submitted_at)! < dateFormatter.date(from: $1.submitted_at)! }
```

Below is the error -

```
specialized MutableCollection<>._insertionSort(within:sortedEnd:by:) + 74
```

below is the code unique array is constructed

```
extension Array {
func unique<T:Hashable>(map: ((Element) -> (T)))  -> [Element]{
    var set = Set<T>() //the unique list kept in a Set for fast retrieval
    var arrayOrdered = [Element]() //keeping the unique list of elements but ordered
    for value in self {
        if !set.contains(map(value)) {
            set.insert(map(value))
            arrayOrdered.append(value)
        }
    }

    return arrayOrdered
}
}
```

the object in unique array is below

```
class MessageViewModel{

 var type: String
var id: String
var to_user: String
var from_user : String
var message: String
var submitted_at: String
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: How are constructed your object in the `unique` array ?

Comment: extension Array {
    func unique<T:Hashable>(map: ((Element) -> (T)))  -> [Element] {
        var set = Set<T>() //the unique list kept in a Set for fast retrieval
        var arrayOrdered = [Element]() //keeping the unique list of elements but ordered
        for value in self {
            if !set.contains(map(value)) {
                set.insert(map(value))
                arrayOrdered.append(value)
            }
        }

        return arrayOrdered
    }
}

Comment: Edit your question and add this to it please.. it's not readable in the comments

Comment: What I meant was the object struct stored IN the unique array..

Comment: So it is the sorting that crashes? Could you add the actual error message? Or even better a reproducible example.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson above I have added error message which is from firebase crashlytics not able to reproduce at my end.

Comment: @DavidAnsermot added object in unique array

Comment: You have a force unwrap of your date conversions. Start by eliminating that.